# jcraft jsch throws "inputstream closed" exception

Tags: java, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

When downloading a file close to 2 GB size from remote FTP site, we are seeing the below error and not able to proceed. Interesting thing is file gets downloaded but probably during final stages it encounters this exception. Anyone encountered this issue? Could you please help about how to handle this exception?

jsch version used - 0.1.51

```
4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:1160)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1006)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:984)
    at SFTPTest.main(SFTPTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2884)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2908)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:2446)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._sendCLOSE(ChannelSftp.java:2465)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:1155)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Post a log file + Post a log of any commandline/GUI SFTP client that can download the file without any problem (if there's any), when running using the same credentials and on the same local machine.

Comment: With a 2Gb file you are getting to the point where a 32 bit integer cannot track position in the file anymore. There could be issues both on client and server, as suggested by @MartinPrikryl , check with another SFTP client to be sure is a client issue.

Comment: It could be a networking issue or something forcefully closing the socket. Investigate how to reconnect in your code and retry the operation if the file gets truncated.